# Problem with aligning Rust structs to send to the GPU using bytemuck and WGPU

Tags: rust, struct, gpu, memory-alignment, wgpu-rs

I have this Rust struct that I want to send to the GPU:

```rs
const MAX_SPHERES: usize = 4;

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug, bytemuck::Pod, bytemuck::Zeroable)]
pub struct Sphere {
    pub position: [f32; 3],
    pub color: [f32; 3],
    pub radius: f32,
    _padding: u32,
}
impl Sphere {
    pub fn new(position: [f32; 3], radius: f32, color: [f32; 3]) -> Self {
        Self {
            position,
            radius,
            color,
            _padding: 0,
        }
    }
}

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug, bytemuck::Pod, bytemuck::Zeroable)]
pub struct GlobalUniform {
    pub resolution: [u32; 2],
    pub time: f32,

    sphere_count: u32,
    spheres: [Sphere; MAX_SPHERES],
}
impl GlobalUniform {
    pub fn new(resolution: [u32; 2]) -> Self {
        Self {
            resolution,
            time: 0.0,

            sphere_count: 0,
            spheres: [Sphere::new([0.0; 3], 0.0, [0.0; 3]); MAX_SPHERES],
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the shader code:

```
const MAX_SPHERES: u32 = 4u;

@group(1)
@binding(0)
var<uniform> globals: Globals;
struct Globals {
    resolution: vec2<u32>,
    time: f32,

    sphere_count: u32,
    spheres: array<Sphere, MAX_SPHERES>,
};

struct Sphere {
    position: vec3<f32>,
    color: vec3<f32>,
    radius: f32,
};
```

But when working on this data in the fragment shader this data gets completely mangled up.
I think this must be an alignment issue, but the sphere-struct is aligned to 16 bytes like the `vec3<f32>` [source](https://sotrh.github.io/learn-wgpu/showcase/alignment/#alignment-of-vertex-and-index-buffers).

One thing to keep in mind is, that naga does not complain that the shader expects any more bytes than the buffer holds, even when omitting the `_padding` of the spheres in the rust Code.

Where does the problem lie?

## Edit

I separated the geometry stuff into it's own uniform.
It now looks like this one the rust side:

```rs
const MAX_SPHERES: usize = 4;

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug, bytemuck::Pod, bytemuck::Zeroable)]
pub struct GeometryUniform {
    sphere_count: u32,
    // alignment: 32 * 4 = 128 bytes
    spheres: [Sphere; MAX_SPHERES],
    _padding: [u32; 3],
}
impl GeometryUniform {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            sphere_count: 0,
            spheres: [Sphere::new([0.0; 3], 0.0, [0.0; 3]); MAX_SPHERES],
            _padding: [0; 3],
        }
    }

    pub fn push_sphere(&mut self, sphere: Sphere) {
        if self.sphere_count < MAX_SPHERES as u32 {
            self.spheres[self.sphere_count as usize] = sphere;
            self.sphere_count += 1;
        }
    }
}

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug, bytemuck::Pod, bytemuck::Zeroable)]
// 32 byte size
pub struct Sphere {
    pub position: [f32; 3],
    pub color: [f32; 3],
    pub radius: f32,
    _padding: u32,
}
impl Sphere {
    pub fn new(position: [f32; 3], radius: f32, color: [f32; 3]) -> Self {
        Self {
            position,
            radius,
            color,
            _padding: 0,
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the implementation in the shader:

```
const MAX_SPHERES: u32 = 4u;

@group(2)
@binding(0)
var<uniform> geometry: Geometry;
struct Geometry {
    sphere_count: u32,
    spheres: array<Sphere, MAX_SPHERES>,
};
struct Sphere {
    position: vec3<f32>,
    color: vec3<f32>,
    radius: f32,
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vec3` and `array` layout is weird. WGSL more or less matches OpenGL “std140” layout rules, which are not exactly `#[repr(C)]` rules. [WGSL spec section 5.3.6.1. Alignment and Size](https://www.w3.org/TR/WGSL/#alignment-and-size)

- Any `vec3` must be *aligned* as if it has 4 elements — that is, a `vec3<f32>` has size 12 and alignment 16. (No Rust type ever has size less than alignment!)
- [In uniforms](https://www.w3.org/TR/WGSL/#address-space-layout-constraints), `array` elements must have a stride (element size, more or less) that's a multiple of 16.

These rules exist so that GPUs can receive 16-byte alignment for almost everything they process.

Thus, if you have a `vec3` followed immediately by another vector or similar, you must insert an explicit-padding field *between them*:

```rust
pub struct Sphere {
    pub position: [f32; 3],
    _padding: u32,
    pub color: [f32; 3],
    pub radius: f32,
}
```

Or you can put `radius` after `position` and the padding at the end. Either option will fill the gap after `position` to satisfy the alignment requirement of `color`.

You're already OK for the array element size rule since it's 32 bytes as you noted.

Answer (score 0):

After adding padding to the structs to comply with the layout rules they now look like this:

```rs
const MAX_SPHERES: usize = 4;

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug, bytemuck::Pod, bytemuck::Zeroable)]
pub struct GeometryUniform {
    sphere_count: u32,
    _padding: [u32; 3],
    spheres: [Sphere; MAX_SPHERES],
}

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug, bytemuck::Pod, bytemuck::Zeroable)]
// 32 byte size
pub struct Sphere {
    pub position: [f32; 3],
    _padding: u32,
    pub color: [f32; 3],
    pub radius: f32,
}
```

I also had to add 12 bytes of padding in `GeometryUniform` to align `spheres` for 16 bytes, which is the alignment of `Sphere`.